# How to build react-native Android libraries from source manually?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to build react-native libraries from source manually? The guide http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html tells me to modify gradle files, but that will not compatible with rnpm (to link new libraries). I copied some command from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/circle.yml and run in `node_modules/react-native` directory (installed from source):

```
buck fetch ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/modules
buck fetch ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react
buck fetch ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/shell
buck fetch ReactAndroid/src/test/...
buck fetch ReactAndroid/src/androidTest/...
./gradlew :ReactAndroid:downloadBoost :ReactAndroid:downloadDoubleConversion :ReactAndroid:downloadFolly :ReactAndroid:downloadGlog
CIRCLE_BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` node ./scripts/publish-npm.js
```

And then compiled the project with `react-native run-android` successed, but it run failed with message:

> Couldn't get native call queue: bridge configuration isn't available. This shouldn't be possible. Congratulations. (see below)

**How to fix my compilation script?**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Fixed this problem, the reason is my project was created by old version of react-native, I replace some gradle configurations with newest generated, and it works fine.

The wrong line is `apply from: "react.gradle"`, replaced with `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to link third party libraries manually, not using `rnpm`. Also compile using Android Studio, as it is said in RN docs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an open react-native issue. See [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7336).

Answer (score 0):

**Using adb reverse**

1. Check whether device is connected or not by running `adb devices` command.
2. Run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
3. Run `react-native run-android`

**Configure your app to connect to the local dev server via Wi-Fi**

1. Make Sure app and laptop are on the same network.
2. Open your react-native app.
3. you ll see a red screen.
4. shake the device.
5. goto Dev Settings -> Debug server host for device.
6. Type your machine ip address. ex: `ipaddress:8081`
7. Go Back to Developer Menu and Click on Reload Js

Read More

1. [Couldn't get the native call queue: bridge configuration isn't
   available](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7336)
2. [Prerequisite: USB Debugging](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-device-to-connect-to-the-dev-server-via-wi-fi)